# Android - A fragment for each tab

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragmentpageradapter

I am new to Android development. I have a an Activity that utilizes [FragmentPagerAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentPagerAdapter.html) to create tabs. Everything works fine except I want each tab to have its own unique `fragment.xml` file and right now all tabs display the same fragment (`fragment_home.xml`).

I have a suspicion the problem lies in this code:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, 
                         ViewGroup container, 
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

        TextView textView = (TextView) rootView
            .findViewById(R.id.section_label);
        textView.setText(Integer.toString(getArguments()
            .getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)));

        return rootView; 
}
```

---

**EDIT 1**

I have added another Fragment class to represent another Fragment. It has its own `OnCreateView()` method which inflates an XML file called `fragment_overview.xml` and that works fine.

Now I am still stuck with my problem of wanting both fragments to be present in different tabs.

The code below creates an instance of `OverViewFragment` in its `getItem()` method. There is only one fragment returned so how do I make it multiple fragments?

```
public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
        // Return a PlaceholderFragment (defined as a static inner class
        // below).
        return OverviewFragment.newInstance(position + 1);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // Show 3 total pages.
        return 5;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        Locale l = Locale.getDefault();
        switch (position) {
        case 0:
            return getString(R.string.tab1).toUpperCase(l);
        case 1:
            return getString(R.string.tab2).toUpperCase(l);
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, if they all have that same function, they're all inflating fragment_home.  Change each fragment to inflate the xml you want them to parse.

Comment: Excuse my ignorance, I get what you're saying but I'm not sure how to go about implementing it.

Comment: R.layout.fragment_home   change that to the id of the xml file you want to use.

Comment: Yes but then won't they all be inflating the other xml file? So I will need separate onCreateViews?

Comment: Yes, you need separate classes for each fragment type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi you have to create seprate fragments for each tab and link with your tab position. You can refer following repository for learn how to do it.
[FragmentPageAdapter With Tabs](https://github.com/thecodepath/android_guides/wiki/ViewPager-with-FragmentPagerAdapter)

Comment: You have to put "break;" statement in end of each case. E.g case 0:   ... break; case 1: ... break;